# FastField not working as expected in Formik

Tags: reactjs, formik

I'm using latest version of Formik (2.2.9) and have a dynamically generated form of around 64 Material DatePicker controls. Currently each of these is re-rendered twice on each individual focus or blur. Formik's FastField seems to be the answer to that, however using it makes no difference and every input still gets re-rendered multiple times whenever the Formik context object changes. I have read a few forum posts from others having similar issues, but they are all inconclusive as to whether there is a problem with FastField or not.

Is my understanding of FastField correct in that if I have a form and each input is wrapped in a FastField then a field should re-render only when values associated with that field change in the Formik context? If so, then is there a known problem with FastField in latest Formik release and are there any work arounds?

Answer (score 0):

I faced performance issues when i worked in a form with several fields. The behavior of Formik is to set the field value on each keystroke and, consequently, re-render the entire form. I also tried `FastField`, but this made no difference in terms of performance. The solution i found was to build a component that keeps track of its own state.

A "normal" implementation of a simple field with `Formik`looks like. I'm using `Field` but you can replace it with `FastField`:

```js
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
      }}
      onSubmit={values => {
         console.log(values);
      }}
    >
      <Form>
        <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
        <Field id="firstName" name="firstName" />

        <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
        <Field id="lastName" name="lastName" />

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </Form>
    </Formik>
```

The problem with this approeach is that every keystroke in the fields makes the entire form to be re-rendered.

The idea to improve the performance is to wrap `<Field>` inside another component, that keeps track of the field state, and set the value of field globally (in the Formik's context) only on blur. Below is workaround.

```js
const WrappedField = ({ props, id, name }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  return (
    <Field
      id={id}
      name={name}
      value={value}
      onChange={(event) => {
        setValue(event.target.value);
      }}
      onBlur={() => {
        props.setFieldValue(name, value);
      }}
    />
    
  );
};

    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
      }}
      onSubmit={values => {
         console.log(values);
      }}
    >
      {props => (
         <Form>
           <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
           <WrappedField id="firstName" name="firstName" props={props} />

           <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
           <WrappedField id="lastName" name="lastName" props={props}  />

           <button type="submit">Submit</button>
         </Form>)
    }
    </Formik>
```

As you can notice, the form above is very simple and has no validation schema. If you use a validation schema, another optimization is to set the `Formik` props `validateOnChange`to `false` and the `validationOnBlue` to `true`.